# Nvfortran and gfortran are roughly 10 times slower then intel for OpenMP matrix multiplication code

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I can’t figure out why the following OpenMP fortran code for matrix multiplication runs roughly 10 times slower if compiled with nvfortran or gfortran compare to intel.

```
module load intel nvhpc/21.9 gcc/11.1.0
[ilkhom@t019 ORIG]$ bash ./compiler.sh intel
The code is compiled with Intel
Number of threads |   Time (sec)
    1             |      2.33
    2             |      1.23
    3             |      0.85
    4             |      0.67
    5             |      0.56
    6             |      0.46
    7             |      0.44
    8             |      0.38
    9             |      0.37
   10             |      0.32
   11             |      0.32
   12             |      0.28
   13             |      0.27
   14             |      0.26
   15             |      0.24
   16             |      0.23
[ilkhom@t019 ORIG]$ bash ./compiler.sh gfortran
The code is compiled with gfortran
Number of threads |   Time (sec)
    1             |     31.60
    2             |     15.89
    3             |     11.33
    4             |      8.04
    5             |      7.01
    6             |      5.65
    7             |      4.97
    8             |      4.33
    9             |      4.15
   10             |      3.74
   11             |      3.54
   12             |      3.11
   13             |      2.96
   14             |      2.67
   15             |      2.59
   16             |      2.35
[ilkhom@t019 ORIG]$ bash ./compiler.sh nvfortran
The code is compiled with nvfortran
Number of threads |   Time (sec)
    1             |     31.47
    2             |     15.75
    3             |     10.73
    4             |      8.03
    5             |      6.87
    6             |      5.67
    7             |      4.99
    8             |      4.33
    9             |      4.19
   10             |      3.71
   11             |      3.40
   12             |      3.10
   13             |      3.03
   14             |      2.66
   15             |      2.75
   16             |      2.34
```

The compiler.sh script:

```
#! usr/bin/bash
​
if [ $1 == 'intel' ]
then
  ifort -O3 -qopenmp -o matrix_multiply mm.f90
  echo "The code is compiled with Intel"  
elif [ $1 == 'gfortran' ]
then
  gfortran -O3 -fopenmp -o matrix_multiply mm.f90
  echo "The code is compiled with gfortran"  
elif [ $1 == 'nvfortran' ]
then
  nvfortran -O3 -mp -o matrix_multiply mm.f90
  echo "The code is compiled with nvfortran"  
fi
​
echo "Number of threads |   Time (sec)"
​
for nthreads in $(seq 1 1 16)
    do
      export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$nthreads 
      srun ./matrix_multiply
done
​
rm matrix_multiply
```

The fortran code mm.f90

```
program matrix_multiply
    use omp_lib
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: N = 3000
    integer :: i, j, k
    real :: start_time, end_time
    real :: A(N,N), B(N,N), C(N,N)
    integer :: time_1, time_2, delta_t, countrate, countmax
    real*8 :: secs
    
    ! Initialize matrices A and B
    do i = 1, N
        do j = 1, N
            A(i,j) = i + j
            B(i,j) = i - j
        end do
    end do
    
    call system_clock(count_max=countmax, count_rate=countrate)
    call system_clock(time_1)
    ! Compute matrix multiplication
    !$omp parallel do shared(A,B,C) private(i,j,k)
    do i = 1, N
        do j = 1, N
            C(i,j) = 0.0
            do k = 1, N
                C(i,j) = C(i,j) + A(i,k) * B(k,j)
            end do
        end do
    end do
    !$omp end parallel do
    call system_clock(time_2)
    delta_t = time_2-time_1
    secs = real(delta_t)/real(countrate)
​
    write(6,'(1I5,13X,1A,F10.2)')OMP_GET_MAX_THREADS(),'|',secs
    
end program matrix_multiply
```

Performances of gfortran and nvfortran are comparable.
I tried collapsing loops. Also, I tried to explicitly include -Mvect=simd option (though -O3 should already have it). No change, results are the same. Intel is doing something clever which I can’t figure out.
Kind regards,
Ilkhom

The same performance.

Comment: Your loop order is the wrong one. Perhaps Intel fixes it for you?

Comment: Ifort really does some aggressive optimization here, but I am not sure which one. Perhaps it calls MKL? But I cannot find it in the assembly, maybe it inserts the code directly. At -O0 it is as fast as Gfortran, with -O3 it becomes extremely fast. The optimization also changes the result slightly. You should always print some result BTW to avoid optimizing everything away.

Comment: Note that with `C = matmul(A,B)` and `gfortran -g -O3 -fexternal-blas matrix_mult.f90 -lopenblas` (or your other favourite BLAS library like MKL) it will be fast even with gfortran. And much faster than what Ifort is able to do by its own optimizations. One should not really use their own matrix multiplication.

Comment: My final observation: The time Intel achieves is very similar to the time it achieves with `C = matmul(A,B)`. It probably inserts the matmul code there because it recognizes that you are doing a matrix multiplication.

Comment: Don't you need to use `OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS()` to see actually how many threads this is parallelized to?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou: you shouldn't need to do that, OP seems to be setting the environment variable for number of threads from the bash script and the times reported strongly suggest that that is working as it should.

Comment: I changed it and tested it in serial anyway. OpenMP is a distraction here. I also used allocatables as I could not even enable unlimited stack on my system. Relying on ulimit is really fragile.

Comment: I tried to use `matmul` as per a suggestion above. Indeed, the gfortran version gets much faster (to the level of intel). However, `matmul` does not scale when the number of threads is increased.

Comment: I agree with "One should not really use their own matrix multiplication". However, my goal is not just to perform a matrix multiplication. My code (quite lengthy to post here) is quite different to allow a direct usage of `matmul`. It also runs significantly faster if compiled with intel. So, I am trying to understand what kind of optimisation Intel does which is different to `gfortran` or `nvfortran` using the simpler example of pure MM multiplication.